# how to get the position of a click in recycler view and use in fragment to pass it to an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

my adapter program

```
class MusicAdapter(private val context: Homefragment, private val musicList: ArrayList<Music>, var listener:OnItemClick? = null, ) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MusicAdapter.Musicholder>() {
    class Musicholder(binding: SongviewBinding) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {
        val title = binding.songname
        val album = binding.albumname
        val songimage = binding.songicon
        val songduration = binding.duration
        val root = binding.root

    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MusicAdapter.Musicholder {
     return Musicholder(SongviewBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),parent, false))

    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MusicAdapter.Musicholder, position: Int) {
        val currentmusic = musicList[position]
       holder.title.text = currentmusic.title
       holder.album.text = currentmusic.album
        holder.songduration.text = formatduration(currentmusic.duration)
        Glide.with(context)
            .load(musicList[position].artUri)
            .placeholder(R.drawable.music_icon_splashscreen).centerCrop()
            .into(holder.songimage)
         holder.root.setOnClickListener{
             listener?.onItemclicked(currentmusic)

        }

    }
    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
      return musicList.size
    }
    interface OnItemClick {
        fun onItemclicked(musicList: Music){


        }
    }
}
```

Now i want to get the position of the musiclist clicked in recyclerview and use it in my fragment to pass it to another activity as an intent. how do get the position as when i try to get the position it only plays the default position.

My fragment code

```
class Homefragment : Fragment() ,  MusicAdapter.OnItemClick {

    private lateinit var musicAdapter:MusicAdapter
    private lateinit var binding: FragmentHomefragmentBinding

    companion object{
        lateinit var MusicListFA: ArrayList<Music>
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
      val binding = FragmentHomefragmentBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        binding.Musicrecycler.setHasFixedSize(true)
        binding.Musicrecycler.setItemViewCacheSize(20)
        binding.Musicrecycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)
        MusicListFA = getAllAudio()
        musicAdapter = MusicAdapter(this, MusicListFA, this)
        binding.Musicrecycler.adapter = musicAdapter
        return binding.root
    }

    @SuppressLint("Range")
    private fun getAllAudio() : ArrayList<Music>{
        val tempList = ArrayList<Music>()
        val selection = MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC+ "!=0" // to check the file is not null
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE, MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED,MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)
        val cursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,projection,selection,null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED + " DESC",null)//to get data from the storage and arrange in descending order
        if (cursor != null){
            if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                do {
                    val titlec = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE))
                    val albumc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM))
                    val idc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID))
                    val artistc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST))
                    val pathc = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA))
                    val durationc = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION))
                    val albumidc = cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID)).toString()
                    val uri = Uri.parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart")
                    val artUric = Uri.withAppendedPath(uri, albumidc).toString()
                    val music = Music(title = titlec, album = albumc, artist = artistc, id = idc, path = pathc, duration = durationc, artUri = artUric)
                    val file = File(music.path)
                    if(file.exists())
                        tempList.add(music)

                }while (cursor.moveToNext())
                cursor.close()
        }

        return tempList
    }

    override fun onItemclicked(musicList: Music) {
        val intent = Intent(context, Playeractivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("class", "MusicAdapter")
        ContextCompat.startActivity(context!!, intent,null)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
interface OnItemClick {
    fun onItemclicked(musicList: Music,itemPosition: Int){


    }
}
```

and

```
holder.root.setOnClickListener{
         listener?.onItemclicked(currentmusic,position)

    }
```

then Activity or Fragment with

```
override fun onItemclicked(musicList: Music,position: Int) {
     // your item position and programming 
    val intent = Intent(context, Playeractivity::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("class", "MusicAdapter")
    ContextCompat.startActivity(context!!, intent,null)
}
```